# Not able to configure my new dlink 853 router

Tags: router

I bought a new router dlink 853. I have two routers as of now. One for wi fi and iptv , and the other just wi fi. I want to replace the one for wi-fi which is my ISP provided to me. I called my ISP and they told me that no MAC restrictions so I can just plug out and plug in the ethernet cable and all fine. However as in the fairy tales not everything is so simple.
I plugged in the new router and connected the yellow WAN port to the ethernet from the wall and connected the yellow cable from the roter to my lan port and laptop and start 192.168.0.1. I am getting
[image]

I tried wireless and cable setup it never works. ping also does not work.
I set it up for dynamically obtain the ip however no luck. any idea how to fix that issue and start using my new router ?

Comment: Connect it as per your first example and then restart the router to get it to pick up DHCP from the Wall Outlet. Does that work?

Comment: unfortunately I did that several times and still the same.

Comment: You need to ask your ISP if the wall outlet is standard TCP/IP DHCP or some other arrangement. You might also try a full hardware reset of the new router and if you continue to have issues, return it to the place of purchase.

Comment: I called them again, they said it is tcp/ip dhcp -> they told me that even if I connect with the patch cable to the router ( no internet) I should be still able to connect to the router interface unfortunately this is not the case - I am not able to see the router interface

Comment: You may need to return the router. Routers are really easy to hook up and get a connection to the WAN port. So now time to visit the store where you got it.

Answer (score 0):

What leads you to believe that 192.168.0.1 is your gateway? Can you check on your PC if youre getting a DHCP lease (not the one from your ISP).

Comment: on the router and the guidance is says this should be the address. when doing the test the eth is saying unidentified connection. this is the output 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.29.64.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Comment: I think youre output is truncated. The information on the default gateway would be nice to know.
If I were to guess then I think you should try accessing your router on 172.29.0.1 given that the network configuring you just posted spans from 172.29.0.1 to 172.29.255.254.
Can you try to ping 172.29.0.1 and then try to access the router web page through that IP?

Comment: actually this was pre defined range, static so when doing dynamic it always starts with 169.254.... the apipa I tested it on teo laptops router reset all the same result. I think router is defective